# How to stop previous page controller from working when changing page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pagination

I am applying pagination on scroll on every page. Everytime I change page, pagination function reloads from previous page as well. This way as I traverse different pages , pagination functions get called everytime from all those page controllers. How can I stop previous page controller functions from working.

Pagination logic is that on window scroll to bottom, trigger pagination function & the page gets more content.

Here is the code:

```
angular.element($window).bind("scroll",function() {
      var windowHeight = "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight: document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
      var body = document.body,
           html = document.documentElement;
      var docHeight = Math.max(body.scrollHeight,body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight,html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
      windowBottom = windowHeight + window.pageYOffset;
      if (windowBottom >= docHeight) {

          if($scope.moredataleft==true && $scope.loadingLoader==false)
            {   

                if($scope.drugnameScroll==true&&$scope.drugSearchScroll==false)
              {
                  if($scope.page==0)
                  {
                    $scope.page=2;
                  }
                  else{
                      $scope.page=$scope.page+1;
                      }
                  $scope.pagination();
              }


            }
          }

       });
```

Comment: If this code is called in each controller then you have to make sure the scroll event handler is unregistered on scope destruction. Listen for the scope `$destroy` event and `unbind()` the event listener function.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos sorry I am new to angularjs and javascript, how do I scope $destroy event. I came across  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
         $scope.MyFunc();
         });

Comment: Thanks I got the solution, $scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
               angular.element($window).unbind("scroll");
           });

Comment: Yes, that is the way to go; remember to give the same function as argument to `bind()` and `unbind()` (if you use the second argument of `unbind()`), i.e. you will have to keep a reference to it: `function scrollListener(){...}; angular.element($window).bind("scroll", scrollListener); ... angular.element($window).unbind("scroll", scrollListener);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution using $destroy event in angularjs. 
I had to unbind the scroll event handler as suggested by @Nikos in comment to stop its working when controller is destroyed.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy',function(){ 
  angular.element($window).unbind("scroll"); 
});
```